# Windows concurrency runtime task scheduling with exceptions

Tags: c++, windows, ppl, concurrency-runtime

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx),

> A task-based continuation is always scheduled for execution when the antecedent task finishes, even when the antecedent task is canceled or **throws an exception**.

I don't understand this because I tried out the following code and the subsequent task isn't called when the first task has finished by throwing an exception. I understand why it must forward the call to the site where `concurrency::task::wait` is called but I don't understand what the statement on MSDN means. What am I misunderstanding?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ppl.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    concurrency::task<void> task;
    auto task_ticket = concurrency::create_task([]()
    {
        // A continuation task executed asynchronously
        // after the previous task has completed. This
        // is executed even if the previous task fails
        // by being cancelled or throwing an exception.
        throw std::runtime_error("Hello");
    })

        .then([]()
    {
        // This should be executed even though the
        // previous task failed.
        cout << "Task (2) executed" << endl;
    });

    try
    {
        task_ticket.wait();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        cout << "Exception caught\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding [Value-Based Versus Task-Based Continuations.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx#value-versus-task)

> Given a task object whose return type is T, you can provide a value of type T or task to its continuation tasks. A continuation that takes type T is known as a value-based continuation.

Your initial call to create_task returns `task<void>`. The lambda you pass to `.then` accepts `void` as input (since `.then([]()` is equivalent to `.then([](void)`), therefore the continuation is value-based and does not run if the antecedent task throws.

To declare a task-based continuation, use:

```
auto task_ticket = concurrency::create_task([]()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Hello");
})
.then([](task<void> antecedent_task)
{
    cout << "Task (2) executed" << endl;
    antecedent_task.get(); // re-throws std::runtime_error
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. It should also be noted that you can't call `antecedent_task.get()` inside of the continuation task.

P.S. Your code needs some fixing (missing braces in the second lambda) and I can't make edits shorter than x chars.

Comment: I just noticed the missing braces as well, thanks. You can definitely call `antecedent_task.get()` inside a continuation, as per the linked MSDN doc: "A task-based continuation is always scheduled for execution when the antecedent task finishes, even when the antecedent task is canceled or throws an exception. You can then call task::get to get the result of the antecedent task"

Comment: Aha, that's correct. I called `antecedent_task.get()` before printing thus it was re-throwing before I printed.